# Cannot convert from char*** to char**

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm trying to create a char** containing some strings that I read from a file but when I try to create it it I get an error saying:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char ***' to 'char **'
```

`

```
Portion of code with the error:

//limit defined above this
char** re = new (char**)[limit]; <---------- Error
for(int x = 0; x<limit;x++) {
    re[x]=(char*)stringsfromfile[x].c_str();
}
```

I've only been writing c++ for a short time now and I can't understand why I'm getting this error. Searched around the internet for an answer for a couple of hours and still can't find anything. If I've been unclear I apologize, please tell me what I've been unclear on.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably should be using `std::string` instead of `char`.

Comment: `new (char**)[limit]` is creating a new `char` pointer to a pointer to an array.  This is three levels of pointers, not two as in `char**`.

Comment: Duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827688/error-c2440-cannot-convert-from-const-char-2-to-char)

Comment: @Bmize729, the only similarity I can see with that other question is the words `cannot`,` `concert`, `from` and `to` :-) It's a totally different problem, using `"` rather than `'` when copying chars.

Comment: @Anycorn I'm turning it into a string later but for some reason visual studio gives me an error if I try to return a string* (Searched error and apparently dlls can't export functions that return string*. No idea why) Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to create an array of char pointers, which means you should be using:

```
char** re = new (char*)[limit];
```

However, you may want to consider embracing some of the non-C aspects of C++, such as vectors - you'll find your productivity greatly increases.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked. I did consider using vectors but I'm still trying to figure out how to use itterators to go through them. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasS, you don't _have_ to use iterators (though they _are_ handy). You can index vectors just like arrays, with `vec[idx]`, since it comes with an `operator[]` built in.

Answer (score 0):

There is mis-match in Left hand operation to Right hand operation.

- **Left hand**:  char double pointer
  **Right hand**: char double pointer of
  an array (resulting in 3rd pointer).

So if you want to use array you can use like as the example given below:

```
char **re = (char *[]){ "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };
```

However, choices can be used only for linear addressing. For example:

```
printf ("%s", &(*re)[0]); outputs: New Game
printf ("%s", &(*re)[1]); outputs: ew Game
printf ("%s", &(*re)[9]); outputs: Continue Game
```